# Puppet master agent update

Tags: puppet

I´m currently trying to update the agent version on our puppet master. But we´re using the [puppet_agent](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/puppet_agent/readme) module with the option

> package_version => 'auto'

That means it will always use the version of the puppet server. Before a puppet run it is of course the old version so the run will downgrade it to that old version. 
Is there a way that the puppet master know which version of puppet-agent it run without a puppet run?

Comment: I don't follow.  The specified usage of the module in question manages the Puppet version on the target node to be the same as the version on the master that compiles its catalog.  Is that different from what you actually want?  If so, then what *do* you want?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No the setup does exactly what I want, but how to I upgrade the Puppet agent version on the puppet master?

Comment: You cannot upgrade the agent on the master's machine without also upgrading the master, module or not.  Nor *vise versa*.  Their versions are both that of the shared "Puppet platform" on which they run.  Do not confuse that with the version of puppetserver or puppetdb, which are separate components that are typically installed only on a master.

Comment: From that perspective, then, do you have an actual problem here, or just a hypothetical one?  If it's an actual problem then some more details on how to reproduce it would be warranted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is a real issue. We have one puppet master server with everything on it (DB, Server and also an agent). When I do an "apt upgrade" on this server it will upgrade puppet-agent to version 6.10. After the next puppet agent run it will be 6.9 again. That is my problem

Comment: The `puppet-agent` package contains the Puppet platform.  Updating it updates both agent and master at the same time.  My best guess at the nature of your problem is that an existing puppetserver process still has puppet master children running from the original version.  I suggest shutting down the puppetserver service and any running puppet agent service before updating the puppet-agent package, then restarting after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Johns comment is the solution:

The puppet-agent package contains the Puppet platform. Updating it updates both agent and master at the same time. My best guess at the nature of your problem is that an existing puppetserver process still has puppet master children running from the original version. I suggest shutting down the puppetserver service and any running puppet agent service before updating the puppet-agent package, then restarting after.

Thanks :)